# Test paperclip image styles with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip

I have a Banner, with an attached file, using paperclip. Paperclip will create "derivatives" for an uploaded image, using the "styles" parameter:

```
class Banner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image,
                    :styles => {:medium => "300x300>",
                                :thumb  => "100x100>"}
end
```

I want to test this attached_file generation, preferably without testing the whole roundtrip to a disk and so on. I could create a Banner, attach a file and then look on the filesystem if a certain file with certain dimensions is created, but that goes against my idea of testing a focused part, without testing the entire stack.

How can I test if the attached file `:image` has certain styles in Paperclip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `has_attached_file` method does is add the passed definitions to the model. The generation is done by paperclip and shouldn't need to be tested.

Source:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip.rb#L174

However, you could test that the definitions were created properly using the `attachment_definitions` method. Something like this:

```
it "has correct image style geometry" do
   Banner.attachment_definitions[:data][:styles][:medium][:geometry].should == "300x300>"
   Banner.attachment_definitions[:data][:styles][:thumb][:geometry].should == "100x100>"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that I don't need to test paperclip; but when BDD-ing, I'd like to write a test like `it "should have a thumbnail" do` first, then implement it.

Comment: I had empty attachment_definitions[:data].So I got it to work using Attachment.attachment_definitions[:attached_file][:styles][:small] construction.